# Not matching result of apply with daply

Tags: r, plyr

I am facing problem with dapply function while comparing results with apply.
Here is my Program, goal of the program to find the percentage of na in my dataset

Code to create random dataset:

```
td <- matrix(rep(rnorm(200,2,6),100),2000,100)
td[sample(1:2000,100),sample(1:100,20)] <- NA
colnames(td) <- paste0("V",1:100)
td <- data.frame(td)
```

function to find percentage of na values in a vector/variable:

```
na.pct <- function(v) (sum(is.na(v)*1)*100)/length(v)
```

Using ddply:

```
require(plyr)
daply(td,.(colnames(td)),na.pct)
```

using base apply function:

```
apply(td,2,na.pct)
```

when I compare results, they are not matched. I am wondering what went wrong with daply function

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: In the future you should use `set.seed` before `sample` and any other RNG functions like `rnorm` just for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 na.pct1 <- function(v) (sum(is.na(v))*100)/nrow(v)
 na.pct <- function(v) (sum(is.na(v))*100)/length(v)
 res2 <-apply(td,2,na.pct)
 library(reshape2)
 res1 <-  daply(melt(td), .(variable), na.pct1)
 identical(res1,res2)
 #[1] TRUE
```

You can check the difference in output:

```
 daply(td, .(colnames(td)), function(x) length(x))[1:5] 
 # V1  V10 V100  V11  V12 ##here it is giving the `ncol`
 #100  100  100  100  100 

apply(td, 2, length)[1:5]
#  V1   V2   V3   V4   V5 
#2000 2000 2000 2000 2000
```

Comment: any reason daply using ncol in place of length?

Comment: @Sivaji  Could you tell me from where you got `.(colnames(td))` syntax?  I couldn't find it in the help page of `daply`.  So, possibly, it would be a wrong syntax giving an incorrect answer.  When you melt also, the `length` would not work `daply(melt(td), .(variable), length)[1:5]` Here, it gives the `ncol` of the melted dataset. Try also ` length(td)#[1] 100` which is the output you get with `daply(..., length)`